# FacesMessage not showing up with PPR

Tags: jsf, tomcat, trinidad, partial-page-refresh

We are migrating our Tomcat servers from Tomcat 6 (with JDK 5) to Tomcat 7 (with JDK 7) and some functionnalities that were working before stopped working.

We use Trinidad 1.2.14 and JSF 1.2.

We have a tr:table with multiple rows. Each row has an edit button that makes some fields editable. You can save the line once you are done editing. Before saving, we do some validations on the data (in the onclick action) and add error(s) to the FacesContext (see code below). We use partialTriggers to update the  component. 
Now, the errors don't show, but the values in the backing bean are correct. **The partial page rendering doesn't fire somehow**. (So the errors are not displayed on the page).

Code to add a FacesMessage:

```
FacesContext fcontext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage facesmsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "test", "test");
fcontext.addMessage(null, facesmsg);
```

We'd like to know how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed our problem by using the latest version of Trinidad (2.0.1 instead of 1.12.14) and JSF (2.1.7 instead of 1.2).